# Using macro variable as column name

Tags: sas

I am designing a generic macro to do update a table using a macro variable (say X) which is used as a column name. The problem I have is that there are ocassions where this variable X (which is used as a column name in the where clause) is null. Can someone help please

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want a where clause when `&X` is blank, then do something like:

```
%if %length(&X) > 0 %then where &X = 'blahblah';
```

So that the where clause is only created if `&X` has text in it.

Answer (score 1):

If `&x` is guaranteed to be defined but may be blank, then DWal's solution is the way to go.  This is useful basically when the macro variable is a parameter, and will be defined every time the macro is run.

If it may not be defined at all, then you need to use `%symexist()` to check whether the macro variable is defined at all, possibly in addition to the `%length` check.

```
%macro test;
  %if %symexist(X) %then %if %length(&x)>0 %then %do; 
    %put &=x;
  %end;
%mend test;

%symdel x; *deletes x if it exists;

%test;

%let x=;
%test;

%let x=XValue;
%test;
```

I nest the `%if` to avoid an unintialized note.

Comment: It should be `%put &x=` ?

Comment: @rbet No, on 9.3+ this syntax is correct. On earlier versions the equal sign won't work anywhere (except to put the character itself).